# HTMLunit Help Script for checking available classes

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I am a bit out of sync with web programming and getting into HTMLUnit is a bit more confusing than I thought it would be.

Essentially I missed registering a class and need to be notified the moment a space opens but prior to getting to that page dump I need to submit a form with two radio inputs ( with the options "Spring Semester 2019" and the "All Classes").

I am in a weird spot where I want to learn more but also need a working script, so a combination of an answer plus some resources I might not be utilizing would be awesome! For example when I do get to the next page how do I download the html file raw and access the required data like number of spots filled and available in xyz class.

https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject

Here is the monkey little program I wrote to get my feet a bit wet:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlRadioButtonInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;


public class hateMerced {



    public void submittingForm() throws Exception {


    }





        public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            // Get the first page

            HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject");


           // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
            // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
            final HtmlForm form =  page1.getFormByName("xhwschedule.P_ViewSchedule");
          HtmlRadioButtonInput radioButton = (HtmlRadioButtonInput) page1.getElementById("201910");
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
            HtmlRadioButtonInput radioButton2 = (HtmlRadioButtonInput) page1.getElementById("N");
           radioButton2.setChecked(true);


           final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("View Class Schedule");
        //    Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        //    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();



            webClient.close();


    }

}
```

And Here is the lovely error I get:

```
Jan 16, 2019 1:09:57 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter error
SEVERE: error: message=[illegally formed XML syntax] sourceName=[script in https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject from (11, 54) to (39, 10)] line=[38] lineSource=[// End script hiding -->] lineOffset=[24]
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: illegally formed XML syntax (script in https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject from (11, 54) to (39, 10)#38)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:892)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:616)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:723)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:689)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:735)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:922)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:316)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:396)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:267)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:802)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:758)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1194)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1134)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:221)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:314)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3179)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2132)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:939)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1001)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:250)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:196)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:267)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:158)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:531)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:398)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:466)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
    at FuckMerced.main(FuckMerced.java:34)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegally formed XML syntax (script in https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject from (11, 54) to (39, 10)#38)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:260)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:232)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:228)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.TokenStream.getNextXMLToken(TokenStream.java:1287)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.TokenStream.getFirstXMLToken(TokenStream.java:1136)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.xmlInitializer(Parser.java:2666)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2641)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2568)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2552)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2533)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2508)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2480)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2469)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2458)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2447)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2436)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2425)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2389)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:2345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:2324)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1282)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:1136)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:673)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:594)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1583)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:216)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1572)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$1.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:714)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:877)
    ... 34 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegally formed XML syntax (script in https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject from (11, 54) to (39, 10)#38)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:260)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:232)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:228)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.TokenStream.getNextXMLToken(TokenStream.java:1287)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.TokenStream.getFirstXMLToken(TokenStream.java:1136)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.xmlInitializer(Parser.java:2666)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2641)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2568)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2552)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2533)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2508)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2480)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2469)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2458)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2447)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2436)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2425)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2389)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:2345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:2324)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1282)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:1136)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:673)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:594)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1583)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:216)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1572)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$1.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:714)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:877)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:616)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:723)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:689)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:735)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:922)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:316)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:396)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:267)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:802)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:758)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1194)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1134)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:221)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:314)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3179)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2132)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:939)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1001)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:250)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:196)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:267)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:158)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:531)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:398)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:466)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
    at FuckMerced.main(FuckMerced.java:34)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers
var submitcount=0;
function checkSubmit() {
if (submitcount == 0)
{
submitcount++;
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Your changes have already been submitted.");
return false;
}
}
// End script hiding -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31337262-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
// End script hiding -->

======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

And here is the HTML of the form I am accessing in case the link is being weird:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" NAME="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" NAME="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="/css/web_defaultapp.css" TYPE="text/css">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="/css/web_defaultprint.css" TYPE="text/css" media="print">
<TITLE>Search Courses by Subject</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" NAME="Default_Script_Language" CONTENT="text/javascript">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers
var submitcount=0;
function checkSubmit() {
if (submitcount == 0)
{
submitcount++;
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Your changes have already been submitted.");
return false;
}
}
// End script hiding -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31337262-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
// End script hiding -->
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class="headerwrapperdiv">
<TABLE CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This table displays Menu Items and Banner Search textbox."
WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault"></TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault"><p class="rightaligntext"></p>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<DIV class="pagetitlediv">
<TABLE CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This table displays title and static header displays."
WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault"><br /><br /><br /></TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault"><p class="rightaligntext"></p>
<DIV class="staticheaders">
</div>
</TD></TR><TR>
<TD width="100%" colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<DIV class="pagebodydiv">
UC Merced Schedule--Search Courses by Term or Subject <H4> 
Interested in UC Online courses offered at other UC campuses?  Check out information at <a href="http://crossenroll.universityofcalifornia.edu/" target="_blank">UC Online</a>.




<FORM ACTION="xhwschedule.P_ViewSchedule" METHOD="post">
<TABLE  CLASS="plaintable" >
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="2" CLASS="pldefault">Select a Term:</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201820" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Summer Semester 2018 - All Courses</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201820 - S6" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Summer Semester 2018 - First 6-week Summer Session</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201820 - S62" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Summer Semester 2018 - Second 6-week Summer Session</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201820 - S8" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Summer Semester 2018 - 8-week Summer Session</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201830" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Fall Semester 2018</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201910" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Spring Semester 2019</TD>
</TR>
</SELECT>
<BR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Subject:</TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<SELECT NAME="subjcode">
<OPTION VALUE="ALL">All Subjects
<OPTION VALUE="ANTH">Anthropology
<OPTION VALUE="BEST">Bio Engin Small Scale Tech
<OPTION VALUE="BIOE">Bioengineering
<OPTION VALUE="BIO">Biological Sciences
<OPTION VALUE="CHEM">Chemistry
<OPTION VALUE="CCST">Chicano Chicana Studies
<OPTION VALUE="CHN">Chinese
<OPTION VALUE="COGS">Cognitive Science
<OPTION VALUE="CRS">Community Research and Service
<OPTION VALUE="CSE">Computer Science & Engineering
<OPTION VALUE="CORE">Core
<OPTION VALUE="CRES">Critical Race & Ethnic Studies
<OPTION VALUE="ESS">Earth Systems Science
<OPTION VALUE="ECON">Economics
<OPTION VALUE="EDUC">Education
<OPTION VALUE="EECS">Elect. Engr. & Comp. Sci.
<OPTION VALUE="ENGR">Engineering
<OPTION VALUE="ENG">English
<OPTION VALUE="ENVE">Environmental Engineering
<OPTION VALUE="ES">Environmental Systems (GR)
<OPTION VALUE="FRE">French
<OPTION VALUE="GEOG">Geography
<OPTION VALUE="GASP">Global Arts Studies Program
<OPTION VALUE="HIST">History
<OPTION VALUE="HBIO">Human Biology
<OPTION VALUE="IH">Interdisciplinary Humanities
<OPTION VALUE="JPN">Japanese
<OPTION VALUE="MGMT">Management
<OPTION VALUE="MBSE">Materials & BioMat Sci & Engr
<OPTION VALUE="MSE">Materials Science & Engr
<OPTION VALUE="MATH">Mathematics
<OPTION VALUE="ME">Mechanical Engineering
<OPTION VALUE="MIST">Mgmt of Innov, Sust, and Tech
<OPTION VALUE="NSUS">Nat Sciences Undergrad Studies
<OPTION VALUE="NSED">Natural Sciences Education
<OPTION VALUE="PHIL">Philosophy
<OPTION VALUE="PHYS">Physics
<OPTION VALUE="POLI">Political Science
<OPTION VALUE="PSY">Psychology
<OPTION VALUE="PH">Public Health
<OPTION VALUE="PUBP">Public Policy
<OPTION VALUE="QSB">Quantitative & Systems Biology
<OPTION VALUE="SCS">Social Sciences
<OPTION VALUE="SOC">Sociology
<OPTION VALUE="SPAN">Spanish
<OPTION VALUE="SPRK">Spark
<OPTION VALUE="USTU">Undergraduate Studies
<OPTION VALUE="WCH">World Cultures & History
<OPTION VALUE="WH">World Heritage
<OPTION VALUE="WRI">Writing
</SELECT>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="openclasses" VALUE="Y" CHECKED>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">Open Classes Only</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="openclasses" VALUE="N">
<TD CLASS="pldefault">All Classes</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<BR>
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="View Class Schedule">
</FORM>

<!--  ** START OF twbkwbis.P_CloseDoc **  -->
<TABLE  CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This is table displays line separator at end of the page."
                                             WIDTH="100%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0><TR><TD class="bgtabon" width="100%" colSpan=2><IMG SRC="/wtlgifs/web_transparent.gif" ALT="Transparent Image" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="Transparent Image"  NAME="web_transparent" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=3 WIDTH=10></TD></TR></TABLE>
<A HREF="#top" onMouseover="window.status='Skip to top of page'; return true" onMouseout="window.status=''; return true" OnFocus="window.status='Skip to top of page'; return true" onBlur="window.status=''; return true" class="skiplinks">Skip to top of page</A>
</DIV>
<DIV class="footerbeforediv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="footerafterdiv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="globalafterdiv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="globalfooterdiv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="pagefooterdiv">
<SPAN class="releasetext">Release: 7.3 - Developed by UCM SIS</SPAN>
</DIV>
<DIV class="poweredbydiv">
</DIV>
<DIV class="div1"></DIV>
<DIV class="div2"></DIV>
<DIV class="div3"></DIV>
<DIV class="div4"></DIV>
<DIV class="div5"></DIV>
<DIV class="div6"></DIV>
<div class="banner_copyright"> <br><h5>© 2019 Ellucian Company L.P. and its affiliates.<br></h5></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Sorry for the lengthy question, hopefully I can pay it back to the community one day :)

Comment: As said in the error message, your xml is malformed so you need to check that

Answer (score 2):

> I am a bit out of sync with web programming and getting into HTMLUnit
>   is a bit more confusing than I thought it would be.

If you like to automate web page these days you need a basic understanding of web technologies at least Html, Javascript and HTTP itself to be able to figure out what to do.

Lets start at the top - with your

> lovely error

As a starting point open the page with a real browser and have a look at the web console. You will see the same error there; that means the page you are trying to automate has an error (at least one) and your browser simply ignores this.
HtmlUnit was created as a test tool; because of this it is more picky about errors. You have to disable this.

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Next step:
You are trying to access the form on the page

```
<FORM ACTION="xhwschedule.P_ViewSchedule" METHOD="post">
```

As the method name implies 'getFormByName()' is able to find forms having the right name attribute - but your form does not have one.

Next step:

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="validterm" VALUE="201910" CHECKED>
```

As the method name implies 'getElementById("201910")' is able to find elements having the right id attribute - but your radio button does not have one.

And the same for the button.
Below you can find a quick hack that does the work. It might help to read at least the [HtmlUnit - Getting Started with HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) page. There is also the javadoc available with detailed descriptions.

Hope that helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "https://mystudentrecord.ucmerced.edu/pls/PROD/xhwschedule.p_selectsubject";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();

        final HtmlForm form =  page.getForms().get(0);
        for (DomElement elem : form.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")) {
            if (elem instanceof HtmlRadioButtonInput) {
                HtmlRadioButtonInput radioButton = (HtmlRadioButtonInput) elem;
                if ("201910".equals(radioButton.getValueAttribute())
                        || "N".equals(radioButton.getValueAttribute())) {
                    radioButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }

        for (DomElement elem : form.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")) {
            if (elem instanceof HtmlSubmitInput) {
                if ("View Class Schedule".equals(elem.getAttribute("value"))) {
                    elem.click();
                }
            }
        }
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();

        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }
}
```

Comment: Buddy truly made my day I will read up on the docs and post back by tonight if I am able to get it working. Thank you man! This is exactly what I was looking for